# colour the high posterior density region in ggplot hisrogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram, density-plot

I am trying to colour my ggplot2 histogram with different colours. To do this I have try, after some research, the following code. The only problem is the legend that I cannot control and it is imprecise.

```
rdf <- data.frame(r=rSample)
r_lower = quantile(rSample,0.05)
r_upper = quantile(rSample,0.95)
rdf$breaks <- cut(rdf$r, breaks = c(r_lower,r_upper) )
rplot <- ggplot(rdf, aes(r, colour=breaks, fill=breaks)) +
         geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, closed = "left", boundary=0, 
         alpha = 0.7, size = 0.1) +
         #theme(legend.position = "none") +
         labs( 
         x = "", y = "",
         title = "Posterior distribution of r",
         caption = "the red area represents the high posterior density region") 
         
rplot
```

[image]

The legend that I want have to say something like "red" = "high posterior density region" and "grey" = "low posterior density region". Any ideas or suggestions?

Many thanks.

Comment: See `?scale_colour_discrete`; I would be happy to reply with a full response if you could provide a reproducible example (i.e. share your data)

Comment: your example is *almost* reproducible (where does `rSample` come from? Is it e.g. the output of `rlnorm()` ?  For what it's worth, what you're showing here is **not** what people usually refer to as the "highest posterior density (HPD) interval"; what you show is determined by tail areas rather than by a density cutoff (see `coda::HPDinterval()`)

Comment: I have no problems in sharing data but I do not know how to add a vector of 40 000 realizations here. However `scale_colour_discrete(labels=c("HPD","LPD"))` solve my problem so many thanks. @BenBolker thank you for having pointed out my error about the computation of the HPD, I had indeed got it wrong despite I think that for unimodal symmetric distribution the result is very similar.

Comment: (1) Glad you solved your problem, you are encouraged to post your own answer (you may have to wait for some minimum waiting period to expire). (2) you don't really need 40,000 realizations to demonstrate the problem - even 100 would probably make a fine **minimal** reproducible example, or you could show code using `rlnorm()` or some other random generator. (3) For a symmetric distribution, it's true that HPD and quantile intervals are identical. (The example you show is clearly not symmetric ...)